# How to delete pushed commits and revert to old commit?

Tags: git

My situation:
On my branch origin webshop

I need to delete the 2 above commits and revert the whole project back to the 3rd commit.

How do i achieve this?
[image]

i Tried:

```
git reset --hard 69697a5
```

But this keeps the other 2 commits..

Comment: You can try "git reset HEAD~2 --hard". It should be equivalent to what you've tried. But it's worth a try

Comment: If it's pushed you have to force push. But this is dangerous — so no direct paste&copy command line.

Comment: `git push --force`

Comment: @TedCassirer if i want to back off this "git reset HEAD~2 --hard", how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend deleting commits that are already pushed to a remote. This can lead to much confusion for other contributors. Therefore I'd recommend you to revert the commits locally and then push your results: [git-revert Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html).

If you need to truly delete the commits you should first do `git reset --hard COMMIT` has you have already done. To delete the commits on the remote you need to rewrite it's history aswell using `git push --force`. You can find further documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).